# Abstract type definitions f#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, f#, abstract-class

I am looking to define a couple of types in an interface or abstract class with the implementation left unspecified.
I then want to inherit from this interface in another, so that i can specify my methods in interface2 with the types that were defined in the first interface.

Eg:

```
type Interface1 =
      type MyType1
      type MyType2

type Interface2 =
      inherit Interface1
      abstract member method1 : MyType1*MyType2 -> int


Module MyModule =
```

The idea is that i want the module to then implement interface2, so it should implement MyType1 and MyType2, and method1.

The reason i'm not doing all this in a signature file is because i want to be able to implement type1 and 2 in c# as well, but implementing Interface1.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: For a start, signature files don't really work like header files, so I don't think you have quite the correct approach

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use ML-style module system - this is not really supported in F# and people generally use either interfaces or other abstraction mechanisms instead, depending on the concrete case - what is the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: We are trying to make a generic code base that can be used for developing android games. We have made a generic viewmode-controller part, and we're now trying to define an interface for the model that can be used for all implementations. I.e. `MyType1` and `MyType2` are unspecified in the interface/abstract class, but gets a specific implementation for each different game that can differ however you want.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you really want is to use generics:

```
type Interface2<'T1,'T2> =
      abstract member method1 : 'T1*'T2 -> int
```

You don't need `Interface1` at all here. Then if have `Type1` and `Type2` implemented in C# (or in F# for that matter), you C# class can inherit from `Interface2<Type1,Type2>` and you're all set.

**Edit:** If I've understood your comment correctly, you want to set some constraints on `'T1` and `'T2` such that they implement specific interfaces. The generic names of all this (`'T1`, `Type1`, and so on) is starting to confuse me, so I'm going to use specific names for an example. Let's say that you have a generic `IKeyboard` interface and a generic `IMouse` interface, and you want your library's users to implement a specific keyboard and mouse class for your method. In other words, the `'T1` type above must derive from `IKeyboard`, and the `'T2` type above must derive from `IMouse`. In that case, [type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints) are what you're looking for:

```
type IKeyboard = class end
type IMouse = class end

type IInputDevices =
    abstract member getInput<'K,'M when 'K :> IKeyboard and 'M :> IMouse> : 'K*'M -> int
```

Comment: I think this could work, though I would like an interface specifying the types so that a user of our library knows that he has to implement these types both in c# and f#. Is this possible somehow? I would also like to define other types from `Type1` and `Type2` in the interface, but i cannot seem to find any way to define types in an interface

Comment: I just added to my answer, with what I *think* you're looking for.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your answer, so i'll try to explain my problem more in depth. I want to make the user implement 2 types, `Position` and `Element`. They should always specify these types, but they can decide what they should be. (e.g. `int` or `char`...). Then i want to implement other types `GameBoard` and `GameMove`. These should always be `GameBoard = Element list` and `GameMove = Position * Element`. I also want to implement methods that depend on my types. E.g. `IsValidGameMove : GameMove -> bool` and `CreateGameBoardFromList : Element list -> GameBoard`

Comment: I can implement exactly this with a signature file, but then i have a problem when i want the c# code to also be able to create objects of type `Position` and `Element`

Comment: Then I think I'm agreeing with Tomas Petricek's comment from a week ago: unfortunately, I don't think you can do what you want in F#'s type system as it currently stands. It sounds like what you need is to be able to write `module Foo<'Position,'Element>`, and then use those types `'Position` and `'Element` in your module (and ultimately, the user of your module would define those generic types). Since F# modules compile to .Net static classes, that would be possible *in theory*, but I don't think the F# type system currently allows it.

Comment: If you want to ask for this to be implemented, https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions is the place to suggest new features in F#. Search though the issues in that project first, to make sure that nobody has previously asked for `module<'T>` to be allowed, then write up a suggestion.

Comment: OKay, thanks a lot for the answers. I have implemented a workaround meanwhile, where i'm simpply using a signature file and have implemented toPosition and toElement methods. I have specified them as: `ToPosition: obj -> Position` and `ToElement : obj -> Element`, and then the c# code have an instance of the module containing these methods so it is able to create the objects.